# How to solve shortening url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to shorten a url for SEO optimisation .I have managed to solve some of the problems but i did not manage for other urls. I have this url for my site 
http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?Ad=Other%20ladys%20Fashion&page=1 , after shortening it http://www.deffsale.com/Other-ladys-Fashion/1. This url is not functioning well after shortening it but if i try another url returning an ad of one word for example http://www.deffsale.com/AllAds/?Ad=Travel&page=1 and shorten it as http://www.deffsale.com/travel/1, is working well.What might be the problem ? This is my htaccess code

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)  AllAds/?Ad=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually problem due to hyphens in your pretty URL. Your internal URL requires space or `%20` but your pretty URL has hyphens.

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^([ \w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$" AllAds/?Ad=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And pretty URL as:

```
http://www.deffsale.com/Other%20ladys%20Fashion/1
```

Comment: `http://www.deffsale.com/Other%20ladys%20Fashion/1` works fine for me. Earlier it was giving 404 to me.

Comment: Oh thanks and how can i exclude the %20 and replace it (-)

Comment: You can even use `http://www.deffsale.com/Other-ladys-Fashion/1` URL but then inside the PHP code do a `str_replcace` of hyphen to space before making database query.

Comment: okey let me try this out .. I have never used str_replace before but i just request to give me an example please

Comment: You can try: `$ad = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['Ad');` and use `$ad` for database queries